# How to ensure two dropdownlists from a common source do not have the same value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my application, a page contains two dropdownlist which have the same source. Take for example, the form creates a bus route. In the form, there is a `DepartureTerminal dropdownlist` and a `DestinationTerminal dropdownlist` which both have `Terminal` table has their source.

The challenge is I want to ensure that user does not create a route with the same departure and destination.

Here's my view model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Departure Terminal is required")]
    [Description("The starting terminal where the bus will move from")]
    [Display(Name = "Departure Terminal *")]
    public string DepartureTerminal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Destination Terminal *")]
    [Description("The terminal the bus will stop at")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Destination Terminal is required")]
    public string DestinationTerminal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bus Fare *")]
    [Description("The amount the route cost")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bus Fare is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Amount")]
    public decimal BusFare { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Route Type *")]
    [Description("State if the route is a long journey or not")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Route Type is required")]
    public string RouteType { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (DepartureTerminal == DestinationTerminal)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Your departure terminal cannot be the same as your destination terminal.");
    }
```

This model does not validate. Pleas ehelp

Comment: What's the problem? You have validation that fails if departure and destination are the same. You have to be mores specific on what you want that you don't already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to resolve this. It was just an error of omission. The class of the model should have inherited from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.IValidatableObject` and implemented `Validate` method. The complete model is:

```
public class BusRouteViewModel : IValidatableObject 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Departure Terminal is required")]
    [Description("The starting terminal where the bus will move from")]
    [Display(Name = "Departure Terminal *")]
    public string DepartureTerminal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Destination Terminal *")]
    [Description("The terminal the bus will stop at")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Destination Terminal is required")]
    public string DestinationTerminal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bus Fare *")]
    [Description("The amount the route cost")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bus Fare is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Amount")]
    public decimal BusFare { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Route Type *")]
    [Description("State if the route is a long journey or not")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Route Type is required")]
    public string RouteType { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (DepartureTerminal == DestinationTerminal)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Departure Terminal cannot be the same as Destination Terminal.", new[] { "DepartureTerminal", "DestinationTerminal" });
    }
}
```

This validates both `DepartureTerminal` and `DestinationTerminal`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is they are both using `Terminal` as the same datasource. If `Terminal` is a DataTable then simply create a new DataTable for either departure or Destination terminal and copy your existing table to it.

You can then bind each drop down to one of your tables.

Comment: I am using entity framework for this. can provide example please